# Working with clipboard for scraping HTML to collect words

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

I have a button on a C# WinForm. Whenever a user clicks this button, it means he is ready to copy a word which he wants to know the meaning of. Then he just copies the word. Finally he shows the meaning of the word.

To accomplish this I used a timer which looks up the clipboard and gets the word from the clipboard by using htmlAgility pack from a website. This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace HtmlAgilityPack
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                string x = Clipboard.GetText();
                Clipboard.Clear();

                try
                {
                    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.bengalinux.org/cgi-bin/abhidhan/index.pl?en_word=" + x);
                    HtmlNodeCollection node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dict_entry']//strong[2]");
                    foreach (HtmlNode n in node)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(n.InnerText);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("no");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it isn't working. There is an exception:

> Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

on the line

```
if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)).
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Open Program.cs and see if Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. Also, remove _timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);_ from _button1_Click_, you don't have to create new event handlers on every click, just do that once.

Comment: The error message clearly says what you should do to fix it. Have tried to do it?

Answer (score 2):

In your `Program.cs` do you have `[STAThread]` applied to the `Main` method?

It should look something like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```